# 管理者権限を持つドライブのメンバー一覧を取得するGASのスクリプトについて

Tags: google-apps-script

[参考リンク](https://qiita.com/o-_-o/items/d6379cd890068ea969ec)と同様の手順でGASスクリプトを作成・実行すると、実行者（自分）が管理者権限を持つドライブの情報のみ取得できるはずなのに、管理者権限を持たないドライブの情報も取得できてしまいます。
管理者権限を持つドライブの情報のみ取得できるようにするにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？
実行スクリプトは以下になります。何かわかる方、情報を共有していただけると嬉しいです。

```
let drv_list, drv_info, drv_token;
let prm_list, prm_info, role_ja;
let array = [];

function myFunction() {
  array.push(["共有ドライブ", "メンバー", "メール", "タイプ", "役割"]);

  // Drive APIから共有ドライブのリストを取得、pageTokenがある限り繰り返し
  do {
    drv_list = Drive.Drives.list({
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: drv_token,
      useDomainAdminAccess: true
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < drv_list.items.length; i++) {
      drv_info = drv_list.items[i];

      try {
          // 共有ドライブごとにパーミッション情報を取得
        prm_list = Drive.Permissions.list(
          drv_info.id,
          {supportsAllDrives: true, useDomainAdminAccess: true}
        );
      
        for (let j = 0; j < prm_list.items.length; j++) {
          prm_info = prm_list.items[j];

          // ロール情報を日本語化
          switch (prm_info.role) {
            case ("organizer"):
              role_ja = "管理者";
              break;
            case ("fileOrganizer"):
              role_ja = "コンテンツ管理者";
              break;
            case ("reader"):
              role_ja = "閲覧者";
              break;
            case ("commenter"):
              role_ja = "閲覧者（コメント可）";
              break;
            case ("writer"):
              role_ja = "投稿者";
              break;
            default:
              role_ja = prm_info.role;
          }

          // 取得した共有ドライブ名および各種情報を配列に追加
          if (j === 0) {
            array.push([
              drv_info.name, 
              prm_info.name, prm_info.emailAddress, prm_info.type, role_ja
            ]);
          } else {
            array.push([
              "",  // 出力形式上、最初のメンバー以外の配列には共有ドライブ名不要
              prm_info.name, prm_info.emailAddress, prm_info.type, role_ja
            ]);
          }
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        array.push([err]);
        continue;
      }
    }
    drv_token = drv_list.nextPageToken;
  } while (drv_token);

  // 配列をGoogleシートに反映
  act_sheet.clear();
  act_sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
  act_sheet.getRange(1, 1, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
}
```